# Why haskell can't infer type for this GADT

Tags: haskell, types, gadt

Simple GADT:

```
data GADT a  where
    MkGADT :: Int -> GADT Int
```

And function without type signature, with error:

```
ghci> inferGADT (MkGADT n) = "123"

<interactive>:14:24: error:
    • Could not deduce: p ~ String
      from the context: a ~ Int
        bound by a pattern with constructor: MkGADT :: Int -> GADT Int,
                 in an equation for ‘inferGADT’
        at <interactive>:14:12-19
      ‘p’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the inferred type of inferGADT :: GADT a -> p
        at <interactive>:14:1-28
      Possible fix: add a type signature for ‘inferGADT’
    • In the expression: "123"
      In an equation for ‘inferGADT’: inferGADT (MkGADT n) = "123"
    • Relevant bindings include
        inferGADT :: GADT a -> p (bound at <interactive>:14:1)
```

If I provide type signature - it's ok:

```
inferGADT ((MkGADT n)::(GADT Int)) = "123"
ghci> :t inferGADT 
inferGADT :: GADT Int -> String
```

If i define term like this, haskell can infer type:

```
ghci> :t (MkGADT 1)
(MkGADT 1) :: GADT Int
```

In first case I do pattern matching, in second - just use constructor to build value.
Why haskell can't infer type in first case? For me it's look strange because I think all information needed to infer type is presented in MkGADT constructor, it explicitly show that `MkGADT :: Int -> GADT Int`

ps. From error message as I understand that it find that a ~ Int and "Could not deduce: p ~ String", why? - function definition given is just string "123"..

This is confusing, what happens here during type inference?

Comment: GADT pattern matching requires the user to provide an explicit type. Indeed `f (MkGADT x) = x` could have both the type `GADT a -> Int` and the type `GADT a -> a` and neither is more general, so the user must pick one of them with a type annotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least two incomparable types:

```
type family F a
type instance F Int = String
type instance F Char = ()

inferGADT :: GADT a -> String
inferGADT :: GADT a -> F a
```

Neither of these is a more general type than the other: taking `a ~ Char` in each these specialize to `GADT Char -> String` and `GADT Char -> ()`. In fact, there is *no* type which is more general than all the other types that can be given to `inferGADT`.

So type inference fails, and demands that you tell it which of the incomparable types you want.